# Enums in Objective-C VS C

Tags: objective-c, c, enums

SA,
What I know is that Objective-C is a strict superset of C..

But when I've tried a very simple enum example that I used to use in C, it didn't work in objective C,

Here's the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef enum 
    {
        SUN, MON, TUES
    }DAYS;

    DAYS d = MON;

    NSLog(@"%@", d);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef enum 
    {
        SUN, MON, TUES
    }DAYS;

    DAYS d = MON;

    printf("%d\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

In C, it works perfectly, but in objective-c (I am using GNUstep on WIN) it crashes when executing (no compile-time errors)

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`%@` is an object specifier and enums are an int (signed or unsigned). To print an enum in Objective-C you need to use `%d` in your `NSLog`.

```
NSLog(@"%d", d);
```

Your original example was crashing because it expected `d` to be an object so it would try and  send the `description` message to an object residing at memory address `1` (the value of `MON`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef enum 
    {
        SUN, MON, TUES
    }DAYS;

    DAYS d = MON;

    NSLog(@"%d", d); //here is your mistake happened, because enum return values are integers.

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

It crashes because of the `NSLog(@"%@")` statement. The `%@` format specifier expects an instance of `NSObject*` (or a subclass), while you pass `enum` item (*ie.* `int`) .

Try `NSLog("%d\n", d);`

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
NSLog(@"%d", d);
```

instead of

```
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

Remember, in Objective-C, not everything automatically becomes an object. Primitive types in C are still just primitive types. Therefore, in `NSLog`'s formatting string, you still need to use the same specifier you always used.

Answer (score 0):

And with boxed expressions, you can keep on using %@ in your format specifiers:

```
NSLog(@"%@", @(d));
```

This is not exactly optimum, but it's really not a problem while you're debugging. If you're dumping string-formatted numbers by the millions, go with a proper number format.